# decentralised eCommerce Dapp

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20

I am trying to build a decentralised eCommerce application prototype for a university project and my background in programming languages such as Java is not so great. I am trying to use Ethereum and ERC20 to enable users of this Dapp to trade with one another directly similar to eBay or Amazon but a server-less system using the power of distributed ledger and blockchain. can anyone give me some advise where to start from as there are not much material online to learn from. this prototype however, will be used to demonstrate it to a real client and investors which I already manage to secure. If anyone is interested to join me please get in touch!

Many Thanks
Mays

Comment: Hi there. I think this is too broad for Stack Exchange as there are likely many ways to do what you want. Reddit would be a better place to discuss your options: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev

Answer (score 0):

E-commerce DApp is actually a very convenient idea of a DApp. As for starting, i think you may need to try other simple ideas of Dapps like voting (Most new dapp starters use it to find their way, including myself).

You can try this tutorial from medium, with its 3 parts. It requires little knowledge of javascript ( mainly jquery ) and some patience to understand solidity, the language in which the smart contract is written and then deployed onto the EVM ( Ethereum Virtual Machine ).

https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2